# The procedure entry point SetDefaultDllDirectories could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

Tags: windows-7, discord

I have tried to do this for a long time. Since I completely formatted and reinstalled my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, I have been getting a lot of errors, one of the main errors that I am getting is when I try downloading Discord I get this error:
[The procedure entry point SetDefaultDllDirectories could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeP2J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Run Windows Update to install all service packs:

- [SP1 KB976932](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB976932)
- [Convenience Rollup (April 2016) KB3125574](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3125574)

If Windows Update still supports Windows 7, run it to see if it can find more updates.

If the problem still arrives, installing [KB4457144](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4457144) should fix it.

Comment: I downloaded the KB4457144 but when I run it, it briefly opens command prompt for a split second and disappears and does nothing. Is this intended?

Comment: It might already be installed by the Convenience Rollup. I suppose that the problem is still there?

Comment: Yes and the windows6.1-kb3125574 says this is not applicable to your computer even though I downloaded the 64 bit version for windows 7 and the windows6.1-kb976932 says that "One or more system components that the service pack requires are missing."

Comment: For the Convenience Rollup, could you have downloaded the wrong version for your computer? After it installs, KB4457144 might work (or be already included).